# MongoDB aggregationCursor '$group' with a keyFn using native mongodb node.js driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm fairly new to mongoDB and node.js.
I would like to assign a keyFn to my aggregationCursor *$group*.

This is working:

```
collection.group(new Code(KeyBuilders.anyFunction), {}, {
    count: 0
}, function(obj, prev) {
    prev.count++;
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results);
});
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
collection.aggregate({
    $group: {
        '_id': {
            $key: new Code(KeyBuilders.anyFunction)
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
});
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: No. You don't use a key function with `$group`. `$group` excepts a document as `_id` and groups documents based on the value of `_id`.

Comment: Found a solution:

`function anyFunction(collection) {
    collection.group(new Code(KeyBuilders.myKeyFn), {}, {
...
}`